# Setting border-radius of a div containing a .swf file

Tags: css, html

When we set border-radius of a div, and then set the code `background: url(image.png)` for the div, then even if the image is greater than the div, the div gets a curved corner. This is because the image is set as background.

But now I face a problem when I want to contain a .swf file inside the div.

Here's the code of the div along with the .swf file contained as object within itself:

```
    <div id="video_container_1" style="height:300px; border: thick; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-color:#000000">
              <object classid="vid:1" codebase="FlashVideos/bride.swf" width="250px" height="300px" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-color:#000000">
          <param name="FlashVideos/bride.swf" />
          <param name="quality" value="high" />
          <embed src="FlashVideos/bride.swf" quality="high" 
          pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="250" height="300" wmode="transparent">
          </embed>
        </object>
   </div>
```

Here, I have already set the border-radius as 5 px. I am testing it on Mozilla, that's why I have used `-moz-border-radius`. But the div isn't getting the curved corner. However if I remove the whole code under `<object>` tag which contains the .swf filecoding, then the div is having curved corner.

Maybe there is a silly thing I'm not getting. How to get the curved corners?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the height attribute and adding padding and see what results that gives.

Example:

```
    <div id="video_container_1" style="padding: 3px; border: thick; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-color:#000000">
              <object classid="vid:1" codebase="FlashVideos/bride.swf" width="250px" height="300px" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; border-color:#000000">
          <param name="FlashVideos/bride.swf" />
          <param name="quality" value="high" />
          <embed src="FlashVideos/bride.swf" quality="high" 
          pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
          type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="250" height="300" wmode="transparent">
          </embed>
        </object>
   </div>
```

Comment: tried the solution u said, but even after applying padding: 3px, nothing happened.. i tried using padding upto 10px but still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Try adding/modding this into your style attribute for the container div:

```
overflow: hidden; height: 300px; width: 250px; border: 5px solid #000;
```

Comment: thanx Matthew, its worked a lot for me, but 1 thing i want to know, if i am not using border: 5px solid #000, then the swf is not getting the curved style, actualy to say its jst effecting the border, not the swf contained within it..

Answer (score 0):

Grant the container with a `padding` corresponds to the `border-radius`, like so:

```html
<div id="video_container_1" style="-moz-border-radius: 5px; padding: 3px;">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: i tried the solution u said, but even after applying padding: 3px, nothing happened.. i tried using padding upto 10px but still the same result

Comment: even now i can see, the border-color is also not effective..i dont know why, but i see all the border related attributes aren't getting effective..

Comment: first, clean all unnecessary code - remove all styling from the `object`, and also clear the `border: thick;` rule. second, check if you have your CSS rules overridden by another stylesheet. third, **use** external stylesheets for styling and supply some more context code, or a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/), if possible. thanks.

Comment: ok, i have removed all the styling from the object..second..i have no other css rules over-ridding my codes..but what about jsFiddle example??

Comment: no luck, i have used the same on another fresh document, to ensure no other css rules overriding, no other included stylesheet codes, bt still the same result

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with jw5 player just by putting border-radius specifications on the container  div, adjusting height and width as necessary, and specifying overflow:hidden;
I did not need to use any padding.